# Using default template parameters to introduce derived type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a template in which I need to use a type which derived from the user supplied type `T` within the `noexcept` specifier multiple times.  In the example below, I need to used the decayed type of `T` multiple times.  The naive approach is:

```
// in this case 
template <typename T>
void foo(T&& t) noexcept(   noexcept(typename std::decay<T>::type(std::forward<T>(t)))
                         && noexcept(std::declval<typename std::decay<T>::type>() = std::forward<T>(t)))
{
  typedef typename std::decay<T>::type DT;
  /* ... */
}
```

The need to repeat `typename std::decay<T>::type` so often seems overly verbose.  I could replace the whole expression with the `DT` type, but unfortunately this is only available in the function body.

The easiest way to introduce `DT` before the function body I can think of is this:

```
template <typename T, typename DT = typename std::decay<T>::type>
void foo(T&& t) noexcept(   noexcept(DT(std::forward<T>(t)))
                         && noexcept(std::declval<DT>() = std::forward<T>(t)))
{
  /* DT also available here... */
}
```

It feels like the wrong thing to add another template parameter just for this purpose though.  So, my questions:

- Are there any harmful side effects to adding the extra defaulted template parameter?
- Is this considered bad practice?
- Are there any other ways to introduct `DT` so that it is available in the `noexcept` specifier?

EDIT:
It occurs to me that the real problem isn't so much gaining access to `DT`, but decreasing the complexity of the `noexcept` expression entirely (as it is used on many functions).  I've added an answer below that creates a custom trait for this purpose.

Comment: what is `noexcept` in the arguments field for? you have so many `noexcept`s there

Comment: I personally think that's fine. The function should deduce its argument anyways, since universal references won't work otherwise. Btw, you can also use `std::declval<T>()` for the argument.

Comment: An obvious side effect is that this is not fool-proof any more: someone could easily use a completely unrelated `DT` and make a mess. I'd avoid doing that in a public API.

Comment: @syam: That someone would first have to specify `T`, which is a parameter that *should* be deduced, since it forms a perfect reference.

Comment: @BЈовић: The first `noexcept` is the specifier for the function `foo`, the second and third `noexcept` are operators that are used to build the expression that is evaluated for the specifier.  In this case, `foo` will be `noexcept(true)` if `DT` is nothrow constructible and nothrow assignable from the forwarded value of `t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just thought of a more workable solution that the one I had previously accepted.  Instead of creating a wrapper template function for every time I have a complex `noexcept` expresion, I can introduce a custom trait.  That way I can easily reuse the `noexcept` expression on multiple functions rather than write a wrapper for every function:

```
// complex trait only has to be written once
template <typename T>
struct my_noexcept_trait : std::integral_constant<bool, 
       noexcept(typename std::decay<T>::type(std::forward<T>(t)))
    && noexcept(std::declval<typename std::decay<T>::type>() = std::forward<T>(t))>
{ };

// but can be used simply in many functions
template <typename T>
void foo(T&& t) noexcept(my_noexcpt_trait<T>::value)
{ }

template <typename T>
void bar(T&& t) noexcept(my_noexcept_trait<T>::value)
{ }
```

Even if the trait is only used once, it's no worse than writing a wrapper template function, and if it is used multiple times then the complex expression is saved for each reuse.

Answer (score 3):

I don't feel I can answer the second question of whether or not it is considered bad practice, as I think those are decisions on a case-by-case base. What works for you might not work for someone else.

What you should know about are the alternatives. Adding another default template parameter changes the API and opens up a potential for errors if the caller thinks he is required to provide both template parameters explicitly. This is unlikely and AFAICS usually not a big concern. The API-modification OTOH might be a problem.

In that case you might consider turning `foo` into a forwarder to `foo_impl` and only `foo_impl` has the second defaulted template parameter. That usually helps to keep the API clean. If you move `foo_impl` to an anonymous namespace (or into the `private` second if this is inside a class) the compiler might or might not inline it and even the generated code looks like your move verbose and explicit version.

```
namespace
{
    template <typename T, typename DT = typename std::decay<T>::type>
    void foo_impl(T&& t) noexcept(   noexcept(DT(std::forward<T>(t)))
                                  && noexcept(std::declval<DT>() = std::forward<T>(t)))
    {
       /* DT also available here... */
    }
}

// clean API
template <typename T>
void foo(T&& t) noexcept(noexcept(foo_impl(std::forward<T>(t))))
{
    return foo_impl(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

Comment: While this answer works for a single function as given in the question, after sleeping on it, I feel a better general solution might be to introduce a custom trait that can be reused.  See my self answer below.

Comment: @marack I would have suggested that as well, but your `/* DT also available here... */` seemed to imply that you wanted `DT` to be available for the function's implementation as well. If that is *not* the case, the traits class is fine.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Yes I do use the `DT` type later, but it is very simple to define (`std::decay<T>::type`).  Reducing the `noexcept` complexity was the main concern.  I guess if `DT` was complex, I could also expose it through the same trait.  I've upvoted your answer anyway, since it does answer the original question well.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the two versions is that DT becomes part of the interface (template arguments) in the second version.
If this function belongs to an api-interface and DT is not specified in the design you should not use the second version even if the alternative means some more code.
But maybe you could write a wrapper instead in your implementation details.